# Ruby-concurrency TimerTask, change execution_interval from within the task

Tags: c#, ruby, multithreading, concurrency

In [ruby-concurrent](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/TimerTask) gem there is a Timer::Task class, which allows to create Timers run on specific intervals.

Here is an example

```
Infinity = +1.0/0.0

@timer = Concurrent::TimerTask.new(execution_interval: 0.25, 
                                       timeout_interval: Infinity) { logic }

@timer.execute

def logic
      # Change interval to infinity, since task may take a very long time
      @timer.execution_interval = Infinity

      puts "Task doing job.."

      # Possibly long task
      sleep 100

      # Change interval back to normal
      @timer.execution_interval = 0.25
end
```

This is supposed to change execution_interval to infinity, since I don't know in advance how long will task take. As soon as task completes, I change execution_interval back to 0.25, and the task is supposed to run once again. However, in this example the task seems to run only once (second execution_interval change doesn't seem to have effect).

I'm projecting the logic from C# Timers, where this works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the scheduled task is here the wrong abstraction.
I would use an [async](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/Async.html) job. You could use something like this:

```
class AsyncLogic
  include Concurrent::Async
  def logic
    # Change interval to infinity, since task may take a very long time
    @timer.execution_interval = Infinity

    puts "Task doing job.."

    # Possibly long task
    sleep 100

    # Change interval back to normal
    @timer.execution_interval = 0.25
  end
end

async_job = AsyncLogic.new
loop do
  job_state = async_job.async.logic      
  until job_state.complete
    # do something meaningful here
  end
end
```